# Использование C или С++ ?

Tags: c, c++

Изучаю "Си" недавно, после Java начал, сам язык очень понравился, минимум абстракций, очень простой и сложный одновременно. Вопрос в том что не вижу грани когда нужно использовать Си, а когда С++, "плюсы" я не знаю и представляю их себе как чистый "Си" только с прекрученным ООП и возникает вопрос: смысл использовать С++ если тоже можно написать на "Си" и он однозначно проще плюсов ?! Просто вакансии в основном на С++ вот и решил задать вопрос типа а как же Си, если везде используют "плюсы" ...

Comment: Не нужно представлять себе С++ как С с ООП. Да, на С++ можно писать в С стиле (много кода на С будет валидным в С++,  но не весь).

На С в основном пишут под контроллеры, ядро Линукса, драйвера.

По факту, многие, кто говорят, что знают С++, знают С и чуточку классов.

Comment: Си - простой и минималистичный, наиболее близок к понятиям ассемблера.
С++ - мощная абстрактная машина, которая позволяет дробить сложный проект на легкопонимаемые части.

Использование С++ дает выигрыш при работе над средними и большими проектами и хорошо ведет себя в командной работе, поскольку позволяет улучшить модульность и понимание проекта. Когда в голове надо держать меньше вещей, становится легче. Взамен вы немного платите лишним генерируемым кодом, скоростью и сложностью освоения инструментария. В остальном, все написанное на С++ можно написать и на Си, затратив порой больше усилий.

Comment: Более понятно, просто после Си взглянул в книгу Страуструпа я сломал себе мозг и стал бится в конвульсиях от С++ это же просто С-- какой-то, он не просто избыточен, он очень сложно-запутанно избыточен !!!

Comment: @Oleg_Samitch Эту избыточность обычно называют гибкостью =)

Comment: Просто книга Страуструпа не совсем для новичков, да и структура книги нестандартная (вначале вкратце описываются все основные возможности С++, а затем начинается их подробное рассмотрение), поэтому она может быть сложна для понимания. Зато гибкость этого языка поражает. Просто каждый должен выбрать для себя те возможности, которые наиболее подходят для его стиля и задач, стараясь избегать тех языковых конструкций, которые потенциально опасны при неумелом использовании (например, множественное наследование)

Comment: @Oleg_Samitch, не стоит начинать с таких книг, как Страуструп)) Он профессор и пишет как принято для ученых: сухим, научным и трудно понимаемым новичками языком, поэтому лучше его отложить на потом. А по поводу избыточности - в С++ намешано очень много плохо структурируемых инструментов, которые перекрываются друг другом. Очень хорошо описан данный момент тут: [Относитесь к C++ как к конгломерату языков](http://goo.gl/gfg25i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто - использовать C++ там, где это возможно. Где необходимо (низкий уровень, взаимодействие с API) можно опускаться к C-подмножеству (оставаясь в рамках синтаксиса C++). Писать на чистом C же есть смысл там, где такие жертвы окупятся, а этих областей не много: системное программирование (специфика Linux), да программировании контроллеров (ресурсы крайне ограничены).

Comment: @Free_ze, или наоборот. Всюду, где нет *не запутанных* готовых библиотечных решений на С++, надо писать на Си. 

(но по сегодняшним подходам, проверять, что компилируется и крестовым компайлером).

По поводу же ограниченности областей применения Си (по сравнению с С++) можно [ознакомится с базой примерно 600000 OpenSource проектов](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=commits&percent=true&l0=c&l1=cpp&l2=java&l3=php&l4=-1&commit=Update), там еще много любопытного, если полазить по сайту.

Comment: @avp ну вроде gcc и без g++ ловит ошибки неплохо.

Comment: Подтянулись хейтеры =) я не буду вступать в холивар, ибо каждый живет как хочет. Я высказываюсь за то, что в С++ абстракция выше, потому писать легче и лаконичнее. А кому-то нравится писать больше, но педантично.

@avp Зачем снова перекручивать факты? Как количество проектов коррелирует с количеством областей применения? Я говорю лишь о тех, где С имеет _объективные_ преимущества перед С++, а их действительно не так много.

Comment: @Free_ze, это не холивар. В области программирования есть одно большое и у всех на слуху направление - создание прикладного софта для ПК и тут С++ доминирует. Но это только верхушка айсберга, которую все видят. Стоит посмотреть глубже и можно увидеть огромное количество областей, в большинстве из которых доминирует Си. Есть, где используется только паскалеподобные языки, где лидируют сверхвысокоуровневые языки и т.д. На ПК на си пишут веб-сервера, СУДБ, мелкий софт. Не упоминув, что С++ доминирует в "областях прикладного ПО на ПК", можно запросто обидеть Сишника с хорошим кругозором.

Comment: @Alexey123 По-моему, ясно прозвучало именно утверждение, что нужно предпочтение отдавать C, когда есть возможность использовать С++. Я понимаю, поспорить хочется, но мои слова перекручивать не надо. Какие языки и где доминируют - это вы обсуждайте между собой. Си **безальтернативен** в относительно небольшой области. Все остальное - вопрос предпочтений.

Comment: @Free_ze, я об одном, вы о другом. Мой комментарий был по другому поводу, а именно пояснение об областях применения конкретно Си, о которых забывают, не знают или не говорят. Никакого спора по вашим вопросам С++, альтернатив и т.п., просто посчитал нужным вставить свои пояснения.

Comment: @Alexey123, когда я писал о проверке крестовам компайлером, то имел в виду не то, что он ловит ошибки  лучше, чем gcc, а то, что надо (не зацикливаясь на этом, конечно) стараться писать такой код, который при желании можно вставлять в программу на любом из этих языков.

--

@Free_ze, вот про личный выбор (в т.ч. оценки что такое *объективно* и как уровень абстракции влияет на эффективность (в широком смысле) программирования) -- это Вы в точку.

Comment: @avp там, где не хватает C, желательно использовать не C++, а языки более высокого уровня. А вот где следует выбирать C++ я, честно говоря, затрудняюсь ответить. (Про Ocaml/F#, haskell и пр. вспоминать не будем)

Comment: @alexlz, а код для 3D-игр основанных на DirectX на Java или Object Pascal что-ли писать? Или все-таки плюсы предпочесть? Да и другие крупные проекты, где производительность краеугольный камень и где чистый С превращается в Адъ из-за сотен тысяч (миллионов) строк кода.

Comment: @alexlz, я тоже так думаю. Наверное, С++ стоит выбирать если значительная часть функционала уже написана на нем и для использования требует именно С++. Все-таки количество уже созданного кода на Си и С++ примерно одинаково. 

@MDJHD, видимо это и на Ваш комментарий распространяется. Наверное (с областью 3D-игр основанных на DirectX не знаком) все основные инструменты в этой области заточены под кресты.

Ведь не утверждаете же Вы всерьез, что возможность созлания С++ классов (+ templates) может дать такую дельту (миллион строк) с функционально эквивалентной Си программой?

Comment: @avp Дельта не только в строках, но и в удобстве разработки. С контролем пользовательских типов, безопасными преобразованиями, исключениями, умными указателями, код получается компактнее и читабельнее.

Comment: @Free_ze, да, многие люди придерживаются такой точки зрения. 

В то же время другие (например, RMS, Линус, Степанов (после реализации им же STL), Керниган (Страуструп тепло отзывается о его участии в создании С++)) не столь категоричны (мягко говоря).

Это мой последний (лимит-с!) комментарий здесь.

Comment: Вклиниваясь в дискуссию, скажу, что улучшенный контроль типов, исключения и умные указатели действительно делают жизнь программиста значительно легче. С другой стороны, реализация их _именно в C++_ оставляет желать много лучшего (на ошибках C++ поднялись такие языки, как Java и C#), так что, перейдя с C на C++, вы где-то выигрываете, а где-то и проигрываете. Другие языки (например, D, если хотите оставаться в нативной области) справляются с этим лучше, но они — оффтопик в данном вопросе.